# requirejs require("text!../path/to/text/file") equivalent for browserify

Tags: requirejs, browserify, browserify-shim, requirejs-text

I have requirejs 3rd party modules that use requirejs and require text files using `require("text!somefile.txt")`

How can I convert this to something browserify can read without any code change as its 3rd party library?

Comment: Are you open to the idea of creating modified versions of the files such as `somefile.txt` as part of the solution?

Comment: No as the library has those files in the module already that we cannot modify